# Can a Node.JS program write to disk if it is ran as a user without root privileges?

Tags: unix

I am about to set up a VPS with a user that lacks root privileges. I also have a Node.JS server that writes files to the disk. If I run this program/server without root privileges, will it still be able to write to the disk successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the permissions and owners for the directories you are using it on and the user Node.JS server runs as. Without more information, no definite answer can be given.

Comment: OK that's what I had presumed, essentially the application will have the same privileges as the user that booted it, and if the application only attempts to write in directories owned by that user it will go through without problem?

Comment: Exactly that, modulo disk space, etc.

Comment: Cool, thanks guys. Would give you some upvotes but don't have the reputation here on ServerFault yet.